# Get array of objects from core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to adapt a method I was using to get a dictionary of ids from a core data request to an array of objects.  However, I am getting confused about what array is the one I want.  Basically, I want an array of contacts with all the appropriate attributes.  Which array of contact objects in the following is the one I want, the `fetchedObject` or the `tmpArray`?

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getContactsNeedingSync
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [IDModel sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"needsync==@1"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    fetchRequest.entity = entity; 
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"cid" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;
 //is this the array I want?   
    NSInteger resultCount = [fetchedObjects count];

    if (resultCount == 0) {
        NSLog(@"result Count is zero");
        return [NSMutableArray array];//nothing in the Core Data store
    }
    else {
        Contacts *contact;

        NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
            contact =  fetchedObjects[i];
            tmpArray[contact.cid] = contact;
        }
        return tmpArray;//is this array I want?
    }
    context = nil;
}
```

Comment: why do you have `tmpArray`? And why are you using `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: Good question.  Adapted from code to get a dictionary of ids...  Should I use just nsfetch? And is fetchedObjects everything I need?  Second part may be redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code creates a fetch request and sets it up to collect a sorted set of objects. You then use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to collect the results for the fetch request. You then have a bit of code which resorts the sorted data (init `tmpArray`).

You can simplify this by removing the `NSFetchedResultsController` and just executing the fetch request directly. The `NSFetchedResultsController` isn't helping you as you aren't adding a delegate to it or retaining it.

The data is also already sorted because of the `NSSortDescriptor`. Indeed, if it was't you'd get crashes as you'd be trying to insert into an array that wasn't big enough... So, remove `tmpArray` and the associated code.